# Can I buy ink pre-mixed to match a Pantone color?

Tags: pantone

Can I buy an already mixed Pantone PMS 377 ink in the market or do I have to mix it my self? If so please how can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you a printing house? are you a designer? Is if for yourt company?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot find the exact ink color you're looking for from a retailer (which is likely), yes you'll have to mix it. You can find the formula for any Pantone color in a [Pantone Formula Guide](https://www.pantone.com/plus-series-formula-guide).

Pantone also has a Customer Help Center that has [answers to lots of questions](http://pantone.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1783/~/how-to-mix-colors-using-the-pantone-formula-guide) related to mixing ink.

Answer (score 1):

You can very likely buy ink that is mixed to match the Pantone color you need, but it's going to depend on what type of ink you need. [Here's one example](http://www.screenprinting.com/green-galaxy-water-based-custom-pantone-match-quart) for water based screen printing ink. Just reach out to suppliers and ask, I'm sure you'll find what you need.